# split string with preg_split on english (and non english letters)

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I want to separate my sentence(s) into two parts. Because they are made of  English letters and non english letters. I have regex I am using in preg_split method to get normal letters and characters. This though, works for opposite and I am left with only Japanese and not english.

String I work with:

```
すぐに諦めて昼寝をするかも知れない。  I may give up soon and just nap instead.
```

My attempt:

```
    $parts = preg_split("/[ -~]+$/", $cleanline); // $cleanline is the string above
            print_r($parts);
```

My result

```
Array ( [0] => すぐに諦めて昼寝をするかも知れない。   [1] => )
```

As you can see, I do get an empty second value. How can I get both the English and the non-English text into two different strings? Why is the English text not returning even if I use correct regex (from what I've been testing)?

Comment: This `[ -~]` is a range between space and tilde, is that what you are expecting? I think you may want `[- ~]+` that will give every english word as its own string, and the non english as one index (or multiples if there were a space). The `-` is a range unless it is escaped or the first/last character of the character class.

Comment: Try `/(.+)([ -~])+$/` I suspect you need to put the text you want to capture separately into capture groups.

Comment: @RedMercury `preg_split` doesn't capture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this regex allowing a caret?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret)

Comment: Do you have two spaces between the two strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to split on boundary between non alphabetic and alphabetic + space

```
$str = 'すぐに諦めて昼寝をするかも知れない。  I may give up soon and just nap instead.';
$parts = preg_split("/(?<=[^a-z])(?=[a-z\h])|(?<=[a-z\h])(?=[^a-z])/i", $str, 2);
print_r($parts);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => すぐに諦めて昼寝をするかも知れない。
    [1] =>   I may give up soon and just nap instead.
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I currently using `$parts = preg_split("/[A-Za-z0-9_~\-!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)]|(?<=[a-z\h])(?=[^a-z])/i", $cleanline, 2);` It cuts off first big letter (for English letters) sometimes though for some reason, I'll be looking into that.

Answer (score 2):

try mb_split instead of preg_split function.

```
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); 
$parts = mb_split("/[ -~]+$/", $cleanline);
```

Comment: `mb_split` unlike other PHP regex functions doesnt use delimiters, but that isnt the issue. The regex is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two spaces between the two strings as shown in your example, you can split them easily with a simple `\s{2}` :

```
<?php
$s = "すぐに諦めて昼寝をするかも知れない。  I may give up soon and just nap instead.";
$s = preg_split("/\s{2}/", $s);
print_r($s);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => すぐに諦めて昼寝をするかも知れない。
    [1] => I may give up soon and just nap instead.
)
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/uD2W1Q